# Undefined method 'to_i' for :Symbol

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, object, symbols

RoR novice here, appreciate any help.

I have the following error:

```
undefined method `to_i' for :funding_level:Symbol
```

Am trying to pass both **funding_level** and **investment_id** parameters from link_to into the **new** method in my controller.

From my understanding, the 100 value gets passed as a Symbol and not an Object, causing problems when I then try to assign it to **@funding_level**, an integer variable.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="investment-status">        
    <%= link_to "$100", new_project_funding_path(funding_level: 100,investment_id: @project.id), class: 'btn' %>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @investment = Project.find(params[:investment_id])
  @funding_offered = :funding_level
  @project_funding = current_user.project_fundings.new(investment: @investment, funding_offered: @funding_offered)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't be this instead ?

```
@funding_offered = params[:funding_level]
```